# Checking for available disk space in Local Machine

Tags: c#

I want to check the available disk space in the local machine using the path ...
This is showing invalid parameter error

```
    string pathroot = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Personal\movies "
    ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"pathroot");
    disk.Get();
    string freespace = Convert.ToString(disk["FreeSpace"]);
    return freespace;
```

Can anyone tell me what the mistake is ? or is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Try with string pathroot = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Personal\movies" (verbatim string)

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`DriveInfo.TotalFreeSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.totalfreespace.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("  File type: {0}", d.DriveType);
            if (d.IsReady == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
                Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", 
                    d.AvailableFreeSpace);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes",
                    d.TotalFreeSpace);

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ",
                    d.TotalSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, this is obviously the best approach. The only pitfall is that you can't query UNC paths since you can't get a DriveInfo object for any arbitraty UNC path (unless you are willing to first programmatically map it to a drive ;-)). But the OP doesn't appear to want that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The string:

```
"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"pathroot"
```

Contains only one escaped double quote. I'm no expert, but I'd expect it to be:

```
"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"pathroot\""
```

However, you're still not actually including the value of pathroot into the resulting WMI query. To do that, you could use something like the following:

```
var query = string.Format("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"{0}\"", pathroot);    
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject(query);
```

I haven't tested it, but I reckon this wouldn't work since "deviceid" expects a string in the form of "C:" and not a full path. Get the drive letter from the full path like so:

```
var driveLetter = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(pathroot);
var query = string.Format("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"{0}\"", pathroot);    
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject(query);
```

Do note, however, that this approach doesn't work when you need to be able to query drivespace for UNC (network share) paths.

Lastly, your hardcoded string with the path isn't escaped. Right now, for example, the \P in \Program Files is being treated as an escape sequence and not as a literal \P. Mark the string with an @ so that it becomes:

```
string pathroot = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Personal\movies"
```

Comment: Why not recommend PInvoke? In any instance that a native API member doesn't actually use WMI behind the scenes (rare, to my knowledge) it will always be _way_ faster. Notwithstanding there's a managed class for this.

Comment: I did, at first. But then I spotted a lot of other things that are relevant to the question as asked, so I decided to skip that recommendation to reduce the size of my answer.

Comment: @Mels By using GetPathRoot() method the value which is getting returned is c:\ , whereas as you rightly said deviceid is expecting C: how do i solve this ...                                                            and the string is not hardcoded it is given as input in a textbox .

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't recommend you go down this path. Either take the DriveInfo approach from Frazell Thomas's answer (if you don't need UNC path support) or take the PInvoke approach as described here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getdiskfreespaceex