# How can I calculate available disk space on Mac (especially with M1 processors) and Windows in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My main issue is connected with M1 Macbooks but it will be good to find a better solution for all platforms. For now, I am using https://github.com/dkrprasetya/simple-disk-utils plugin but I am receiving the "Fallback handler could not load library" error on M1 Macbooks

I have tried to create a custom objective-c library with Xcode (to test for M1 processors) but no luck. Also, tried code from this article [Checking for available disk space in Local Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162930/checking-for-available-disk-space-in-local-machine) but it is not returning the correct size because there may be  virtual Drives(at least on Mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

- [DriveInfo.TotalFreeSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.totalfreespace?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_IO_DriveInfo_TotalFreeSpace)
- [DriveInfo.TotalSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.totalsize?view=net-7.0)

Not sure if these would work with Unity’s Mono or IL2CPP

Comment: I am actually using DriveInfo.TotalFreeSpace and DriveInfo.TotalSize, but after summing all drive's space I am receiving 840GB of space but my SSD is only 500Gb

Comment: @GevorgChobanyan What do you mean summing the total space? You shouldn’t have to add anything in your code. TotalSize includes used and unused space.

Comment: thanks, @SupaMaggie70, it works on all platforms